# resetar variavel incremento javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variáveis

o que preciso parece ser muito simples mas não encontrei uma solução ainda.

tenho esse codigo

```
var countID = 1;
$("#addArma").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tipoCampo = "arma";

    adicionaArma(tipoCampo, countID);
    countID++;
});
```

que incrementa normalmente um formulario dentro de uma função que criei.
O que preciso está na hora de excluir o formulario se necessário, preciso que quando excluir ele decrementa o valor e atualize a variavel countID pra quando eu adicionar outro form ele vir com valor na sequencia certa.

fiz da maneira abaixo mas quando adiciono outro form depois que deleta ele não adiciona na sequencia certa, creio que falta atualizar a variavel countID de outra maneira, obrigado.

```
$('body').on('click', '#delArma', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-valor');
    var element = $('#armaID' + id);


    element.fadeOut(600);
    countID -= 1;
});
```

Atualizei a variavel dessa forma e funciou, porém se adiciono outro form após excluir, por exemplo:

form 1
form 2

deleto form 2 
adiciono form vem form 2 - aqui esta correto.

se tento excluir form 2 novamente não exclui.
Função que adiciona os campos:

```
function adicionaArma(tipo, idContador) {


    var paisFab = "paisFab" + idContador;
    var numArma = "numArma" + idContador;
    var carregamento = "carregamento" + idContador;
    var marca = "marca" + idContador;
    var modelo = "modelo" + idContador;
    var especie = "especie" + idContador;
    var tipoFunc = "tipoFunc" + idContador;
    var calibre = "calibre" + idContador;
    var acabamento = "acabamento" + idContador;
    var qntdCanos = "qntdCanos" + idContador;
    var compCano = "compCano" + idContador;
    var tipoAlma = "tipoAlma" + idContador;
    var numRaias = "numRaias" + idContador;
    var html = "";
    html += '<div id="armaID' + idContador + '"><label class="text-white d-flex justify-content-between">DADOS DA ARMA Nº ' + idContador + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="delArma" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-valor="' + idContador + '"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></label><hr><div class="form-group"><label for="paisFab">País de Fabricação</label><div class="form-label-group"><select id="' + paisFab + '" class="form-control" ><option value="Brasil" selected="selected">Brasil</option><option value="Afeganistão">Afeganistão</option><option value="África do Sul">África do Sul</option><option value="Albânia">Albânia</option><option value="Alemanha">Alemanha</option><option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>    <option value="Antilhas Holandesas">Antilhas Holandesas</option>    <option value="Antárctida">Antárctida</option>    <option value="Antígua e Barbuda">Antígua e Barbuda</option>    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>    <option value="Argélia">Argélia</option>    <option value="Armênia">Armênia</option>    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>    <option value="Arábia Saudita">Arábia Saudita</option>    <option value="Austrália">Austrália</option>    <option value="Áustria">Áustria</option>    <option value="Azerbaijão">Azerbaijão</option>    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>    <option value="Bahrein">Bahrein</option>    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>    <option value="Benim">Benim</option>    <option value="Bermudas">Bermudas</option>    <option value="Bielorrússia">Bielorrússia</option>    <option value="Bolívia">Bolívia</option>    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>    <option value="Bulgária">Bulgária</option>    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>    <option value="Butão">Butão</option>    <option value="Bélgica">Bélgica</option>    <option value="Bósnia e Herzegovina">Bósnia e Herzegovina</option>    <option value="Cabo Verde">Cabo Verde</option>    <option value="Camarões">Camarões</option>    <option value="Camboja">Camboja</option>    <option value="Canadá">Canadá</option>    <option value="Catar">Catar</option>    <option value="Cazaquistão">Cazaquistão</option>    <option value="Chade">Chade</option>    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>    <option value="China">China</option>    <option value="Chipre">Chipre</option>    <option value="Colômbia">Colômbia</option>    <option value="Comores">Comores</option>    <option value="Coreia do Norte">Coreia do Norte</option>    <option value="Coreia do Sul">Coreia do Sul</option>    <option value="Costa do Marfim">Costa do Marfim</option>    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>    <option value="Croácia">Croácia</option>    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>    <option value="Dinamarca">Dinamarca</option>    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>    <option value="Egito">Egito</option>    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>    <option value="Emirados Árabes Unidos">Emirados Árabes Unidos</option>    <option value="Equador">Equador</option>    <option value="Eritreia">Eritreia</option>    <option value="Escócia">Escócia</option>    <option value="Eslováquia">Eslováquia</option>    <option value="Eslovênia">Eslovênia</option>    <option value="Espanha">Espanha</option>    <option value="Estados Federados da Micronésia">Estados Federados da Micronésia</option>    <option value="Estados Unidos">Estados Unidos</option>    <option value="Estônia">Estônia</option>    <option value="Etiópia">Etiópia</option>    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>    <option value="Filipinas">Filipinas</option>    <option value="Finlândia">Finlândia</option>    <option value="França">França</option>    <option value="Gabão">Gabão</option>   <option value="Gana">Gana</option>    <option value="Geórgia">Geórgia</option>    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>    <option value="Granada">Granada</option>    <option value="Gronelândia">Gronelândia</option>    <option value="Grécia">Grécia</option>    <option value="Guadalupe">Guadalupe</option>    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>    <option value="Guernesei">Guernesei</option>    <option value="Guiana">Guiana</option>    <option value="Guiana Francesa">Guiana Francesa</option>    <option value="Guiné">Guiné</option>    <option value="Guiné Equatorial">Guiné Equatorial</option>    <option value="Guiné-Bissau">Guiné-Bissau</option>    <option value="Gâmbia">Gâmbia</option>    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>    <option value="Hungria">Hungria</option>    <option value="Ilha Bouvet">Ilha Bouvet</option>    <option value="Ilha de Man">Ilha de Man</option>    <option value="Ilha do Natal">Ilha do Natal</option>    <option value="Ilha Heard e Ilhas McDonald">Ilha Heard e Ilhas McDonald</option>    <option value="Ilha Norfolk">Ilha Norfolk</option>    <option value="Ilhas Cayman">Ilhas Cayman</option>    <option value="Ilhas Cocos (Keeling)">Ilhas Cocos (Keeling)</option>    <option value="Ilhas Cook">Ilhas Cook</option>    <option value="Ilhas Feroé">Ilhas Feroé</option>    <option value="Ilhas Geórgia do Sul e Sandwich do Sul">Ilhas Geórgia do Sul e Sandwich do Sul</option>    <option value="Ilhas Malvinas">Ilhas Malvinas</option>    <option value="Ilhas Marshall">Ilhas Marshall</option>    <option value="Ilhas Menores Distantes dos Estados Unidos">Ilhas Menores Distantes dos Estados Unidos</option>    <option value="Ilhas Salomão">Ilhas Salomão</option>    <option value="Ilhas Virgens Americanas">Ilhas Virgens Americanas</option>    <option value="Ilhas Virgens Britânicas">Ilhas Virgens Britânicas</option>    <option value="Ilhas Åland">Ilhas Åland</option>    <option value="Indonésia">Indonésia</option>    <option value="Inglaterra">Inglaterra</option>    <option value="Índia">Índia</option>    <option value="Iraque">Iraque</option>    <option value="Irlanda do Norte">Irlanda do Norte</option>    <option value="Irlanda">Irlanda</option>    <option value="Irã">Irã</option>    <option value="Islândia">Islândia</option>    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>    <option value="Itália">Itália</option>    <option value="Iêmen">Iêmen</option>    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>    <option value="Japão">Japão</option>    <option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>    <option value="Jordânia">Jordânia</option>    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>    <option value="Laos">Laos</option>    <option value="Lesoto">Lesoto</option>    <option value="Letônia">Letônia</option>    <option value="Libéria">Libéria</option>    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>    <option value="Lituânia">Lituânia</option>    <option value="Luxemburgo">Luxemburgo</option>    <option value="Líbano">Líbano</option>    <option value="Líbia">Líbia</option>    <option value="Macau">Macau</option>   <option value="Macedônia">Macedônia</option>    <option value="Madagáscar">Madagáscar</option>    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>    <option value="Maldivas">Maldivas</option>    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>    <option value="Malásia">Malásia</option>    <option value="Marianas Setentrionais">Marianas Setentrionais</option>    <option value="Marrocos">Marrocos</option>    <option value="Martinica">Martinica</option>    <option value="Mauritânia">Mauritânia</option>    <option value="Maurícia">Maurícia</option>    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>    <option value="Moldávia">Moldávia</option>    <option value="Mongólia">Mongólia</option>    <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>    <option value="Moçambique">Moçambique</option>    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>    <option value="México">México</option>    <option value="Mônaco">Mônaco</option>    <option value="Namíbia">Namíbia</option>    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>    <option value="Nicarágua">Nicarágua</option>    <option value="Nigéria">Nigéria</option>    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>    <option value="Noruega">Noruega</option>    <option value="Nova Caledônia">Nova Caledônia</option>    <option value="Nova Zelândia">Nova Zelândia</option>    <option value="Níger">Níger</option>    <option value="Omã">Omã</option>    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>    <option value="Palestina">Palestina</option>    <option value="Panamá">Panamá</option>    <option value="Papua-Nova Guiné">Papua-Nova Guiné</option>   <option value="Paquistão">Paquistão</option>    <option value="Paraguai">Paraguai</option>    <option value="País de Gales">País de Gales</option>    <option value="Países Baixos">Países Baixos</option>    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>    <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>    <option value="Polinésia Francesa">Polinésia Francesa</option>    <option value="Polônia">Polônia</option>    <option value="Porto Rico">Porto Rico</option>    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>    <option value="Quirguistão">Quirguistão</option>    <option value="Quênia">Quênia</option>    <option value="Reino Unido">Reino Unido</option>    <option value="República Centro-Africana">República Centro-Africana</option>    <option value="República Checa">República Checa</option>    <option value="República Democrática do Congo">República Democrática do Congo</option>    <option value="República do Congo">República do Congo</option>    <option value="República Dominicana">República Dominicana</option>    <option value="Reunião">Reunião</option>    <option value="Romênia">Romênia</option>    <option value="Ruanda">Ruanda</option>    <option value="Rússia">Rússia</option>    <option value="Saara Ocidental">Saara Ocidental</option>    <option value="Saint Martin">Saint Martin</option>    <option value="Saint-Barthélemy">Saint-Barthélemy</option>    <option value="Saint-Pierre e Miquelon">Saint-Pierre e Miquelon</option>    <option value="Samoa Americana">Samoa Americana</option>    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>    <option value="Santa Helena, Ascensão e Tristão da Cunha">Santa Helena, Ascensão e Tristão da Cunha</option>    <option value="Santa Lúcia">Santa Lúcia</option>    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>    <option value="Serra Leoa">Serra Leoa</option>    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>    <option value="Singapura">Singapura</option>    <option value="Somália">Somália</option>    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>    <option value="Suazilândia">Suazilândia</option>    <option value="Sudão">Sudão</option>    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>    <option value="Suécia">Suécia</option>    <option value="Suíça">Suíça</option>    <option value="Svalbard e Jan Mayen">Svalbard e Jan Mayen</option>    <option value="São Cristóvão e Nevis">São Cristóvão e Nevis</option>    <option value="São Marino">São Marino</option>    <option value="São Tomé e Príncipe">São Tomé e Príncipe</option>    <option value="São Vicente e Granadinas">São Vicente e Granadinas</option>    <option value="Sérvia">Sérvia</option>    <option value="Síria">Síria</option>    <option value="Tadjiquistão">Tadjiquistão</option>    <option value="Tailândia">Tailândia</option>    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>    <option value="Tanzânia">Tanzânia</option>    <option value="Terras Austrais e Antárticas Francesas">Terras Austrais e Antárticas Francesas</option>    <option value="Território Britânico do Oceano Índico">Território Britânico do Oceano Índico</option>    <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>    <option value="Toquelau">Toquelau</option>    <option value="Trinidad e Tobago">Trinidad e Tobago</option>    <option value="Tunísia">Tunísia</option>    <option value="Turcas e Caicos">Turcas e Caicos</option>    <option value="Turquemenistão">Turquemenistão</option>    <option value="Turquia">Turquia</option>    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>    <option value="Ucrânia">Ucrânia</option>    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>    <option value="Uruguai">Uruguai</option>    <option value="Uzbequistão">Uzbequistão</option>    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>    <option value="Vaticano">Vaticano</option>    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>    <option value="Vietname">Vietname</option>    <option value="Wallis e Futuna">Wallis e Futuna</option>    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>    <option value="Zâmbia">Zâmbia</option></select></div></div><div class="form-group">    <div class="form-row">        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">    <input type="text" id="' + numArma + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Número da Arma" >     <label for="' + numArma + '">Numero da Arma</label></div></div><div class="col-md-6">    <div class="form-label-group">        <input type="text" id="' + carregamento + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Capacidade de Carregamento" >        <label for="' + carregamento + '">Capacidade de Carregamento</label>    </div></div></div></div><div class="form-group">    <div class="form-row">        <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="form-label-group">    <input type="text" id="' + marca + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Marca da Arma" >      <label for="' + marca + '">Marca da Arma</label></div></div><div class="col-md-6">    <div class="form-label-group">       <input type="text" id="' + modelo + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo da Arma" >  <label for="' + modelo + '">modelo da Arma</label></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group">    <div class="form-row">        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + especie + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Espécie da Arma" >                <label for="' + especie + '">Espécie da Arma</label>            </div>        </div>        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + tipoFunc + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Tipo de Funcionamento" >   <label for="' + tipoFunc + '">Tipo de Funcionamento</label>       </div>       </div>    </div></div><div class="form-group">    <div class="form-row">        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + calibre + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Calibre da Arma" >                <label for="' + calibre + '">Calibre da Arma</label>            </div>        </div>        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + acabamento + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Acabamento da Arma" >                <label for="' + acabamento + '">Acabamento da Arma</label>            </div>        </div>    </div></div><div class="form-group">    <div class="form-row">        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + qntdCanos + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade de Canos" >                <label for="' + qntdCanos + '">Quantidade de Canos</label>            </div>        </div>        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + compCano + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Comprimento do Cano" >                <label for="' + compCano + '">Comprimento do Cano</label>            </div>        </div>    </div></div><div class="form-group">    <div class="form-row">        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + tipoAlma + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Tipo de Alma" >                <label for="' + tipoAlma + '">Tipo de Alma</label>            </div>        </div>        <div class="col-md-6">            <div class="form-label-group">                <input type="text" id="' + numRaias + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de Raias/Sentido">                <label for="' + numRaias + '">Numero de Raias</label>            </div>        </div>    </div></div></div>';

    $("#" + tipo).append(html);

}
```

Comment: Não entendi direito, você quer uma função para apagar a última variável e então exibir o valor atualizado?

Comment: `countID = -1`, aqui você atribuiu o valor -1 à variável ao invés de decrementá-la. Para decrementar basta fazer `countID--` ou `countID -= 1`.

Comment: Pode colocar o HTML mostrando o elemento que está adicionando e fazendo o index deste ?

Comment: acho que é mais simples, preciso que ao excluir o element, ele atualize a variavel countID que é responsável pelo incremento de cada formulário adicionado, não sei se fui mais claro.

Comment: sim Anderson, eu fiz dessa forma, corrigindo: assim ele me retorna a sequencia que eu quero, porém se eu tento excluir esse novo form ele nao exclui.. exemplo: exclui o form nº 2 -> adiciono novamente ele vem com nº 2, correto, porém se eu tento excluir ele não exclui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não funciona porque ao usar `.fadeOut()` o elemento não é removido da página, ele apenas ganha `display: none` e fica oculto. Com isso, ao criar um novo elemento, esse terá o mesmo id do elemento que foi ocultado, e assim, o click no botão delete irá buscar o id do elemento oculto, porque o JavaScript irá buscar o primeiro elemento que possui o id.

Vamos supor que você crie dois formulários. Você terá duas divs: `#armaID1` e `#armaID2`, e a variável `countID` irá ficar com o valor `3`. Ao remover a div `#armaID1`, a variável agora ficará com o valor `2`. Ao criar uma novo formulário ele terá o mesmo id `#armaID2` que já existe, ou seja, esse esquema de decrementar a variável não funciona.

O certo é você não decrementar a variável `countID`, pois assim você terá sempre um formulário com uma id nova, embora os formulários fiquem não sequenciais, o que não faz diferença alguma e tudo funcionaria perfeitamente.

Porém, faça uma correção:

Troque o id `id="delArma"` por classe, porque você está repetindo-o. Apague esse `id="delArma"` e adicione `delArma` na lista de classe do botão, ficando assim:

```
class="delArma btn btn-danger btn-sm"
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Cara pelo que entendi tu quer que o index de seu elemento faça o autoincremento e autodecremento ao clique de seus botões de add e remove. Isto aqui deve resolver seu problema:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var clone = $("seuCampo").html(); // pode ser .clone() tambem //
        $(document).on('click', '#addArma', addArma);

        $(document).on('click', '#delArma', function(){
            $(this).parents("seuCampo").remove();
            increment();
        })

        function addArma() {
            $('body').append(clone);
            increment();
        }


        function increment() {
            $("[name='armaID[]']").each(function (i, e) {
                $(e).val(i + 1);
            });
    }
```

Como eu não tinha o seu HTML, não sei o elemento que você está adicionando, então no lugar deste eu coloquei o `seuCampo` no código, substitua pelo campo que dará certo. Perceba também que fiz o incremento mudando seu elemento `armaID`de `id`para `name`pelo fato de que nunca é bom duplicar coisas com o mesmo `id`, você pode trocar estes todos para `name`com um `[]`no final declarando que este será tipo um `array`, facilita bastante para você mandar para seu BD, pois ele vai identificar todos os valores ao invés de um só. Teste e me dê o retorno se precisar de ajuda ou coisa do tipo.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, eu atualizei o post, inclui o codigo da função de adiciona os campos em html, pois eu adiciono diretamente com jquery na div #arma.

Comment: Cara, vendo a forma que você faz, acho que poderia fazer um form de maneira muito mais dinâmica do que como está agora. Como eu disse, você pode fazer um contador de ID onde você não precisaria ter o ID na frente de todos os outros itens, entende ? Quando você for mandar para o BD, você consegue identificar cada um pelo ID da linha, não precisa ter o ID na frente de tudo. Altere a forma que voce constrói este Formulário, faça isso pelo HTML ao invés do JS e só manipule através do JQuery.

Comment: entendo seu ponto de vista, porém cada form tem 14 campos que precisam ser indexados separadamente.

Comment: Mas isto você pode fazer fácilmente. Você pode colocar uma DIV dentro do FORM, onde está encapsulará outra ou mais dentro contendo todos os campos que serão input's. Pegando na função ```html()``` desta DIV, você consegue adicionar todos os campos dinamicamente dentro deste form, só manipulando o ID e apenas preenchendo os campos. Quando for inserir no BD, você fará um for() através dos ID's e cada ID terá a linha inserida com seus respectivos campos.

Comment: entendi, não sou muito bom em javascript, essa função .clone() pega o todo o html de um elemento?

Comment: Na verdade não. o ```clone()``` faz literalmente um clone do seu elemento e assim que você adiciona-lo ele adiciona assim como estava o anterior. Neste caso o melhor seria o ```html()``` pegando a DIV pai que lhe disse, pelo fato de que está função pega todo o código dentro da DIV que você setou, com isso você poderia dar um ```append``` dentro desta DIV pai, deixando o código mais organizado.

Comment: show vou tentar isso, aí aplicando seu exemplo acima eu consigo indexar com o loop para enviar pro BD certo?

Comment: Sim, desta forma você consegue enviar todos os itens fazendo o loop pelo ID.